# How to parse using pandas dataframe into database table from space delimated with variation

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a data file like below

```
      Sl  Account.no      Legacy   Account Title           Ac.Category      Withdral Amt  Deposited Amt  Cheque   Transac.type     Trans.Rf.No   Inputter   Authoriser  Point.Name      Time
      1   0000009540000  42545     XXXXXX XXXXX            MODEL Point              0.00        1000.00  --W/C--  Cash deposit -   TT22094CYM5K   BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   11:17
      2   0000009540000  42331     XX  XXXX XXXX           MODEL point              0.00        2000.00  --W/C--  Cash deposit -   TT22094JRQX6   BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   12:41
      79  0000005865000  10000150  A A AAAA XXXXXXX        Current Depo         80000.00           0.00  2363714  Cash Withdrawal  TT220947W4JX  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   13:40                                                                 --------------------------------------
      91  0900013591000  70006405  AAAAA. AAAAAA xxx XXXXX Savings Depo         80000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT220944PRDM  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 8426   13:54
      92  0900017904000  90007086  AAAAA AAAAA             Savings Depo       900000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT220945JFS2  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 2160   15:24
      93  0900018400000  40033910  AAAAA AAAAA             Savings Depo         50000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT22094BYJ1V  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON BR8981       13:53
```

I want to add this into database table where Sl , Account.no , Legacy , Ac.Category etc etc are the attribute and the others rows are the value.

I have tried with below code but not getting accurate result as spaces are not equal in every row and account tile may have spaces as well.

```
      def read_text_file(file_path):
         with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
          global count
          for lines in f:
             #print(lines)
             if re.match(r"^\d+.*$",lines):
             lt= lines.split("  ",5)
             print(lt[0])
             count = count + 1


             count = 0

            # iterate through all file
            for file in os.listdir():
            counters = counters + 1
            # Check whether file is in text format or not
            if file.endswith(""):

                 file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
                 # call read text file function
                 read_text_file(file_path)
```

Comment: IF you could assume that each column was separated by at least two spaces, and that the `-------------------------------------------------------------` string magically goes away then you could do:  `pd.read_csv('you_file.txt', sep='\s\s+')`.  Oh yeah - also assumes that `Account Tile` (and any other data) contains no more than one space between words.

Comment: Unfortunately account title have more than teo spaces and the point name also contains spaces

Comment: Could you assume that the first 4 columns maintain their column widths like in the example data and then things get crazy?  Or is it crazy from the start?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the first 3 columns are fixed width like shown in the example and that the data starts with 6 blanks like in your example then you could do:

```
sim_txt = io.StringIO(
'''      Sl  Account.no      Legacy   Account Title           Ac.Category      Withdral Amt  Deposited Amt  Cheque   Transac.type     Trans.Rf.No   Inputter   Authoriser  Point.Name      Time
      1   0000009540000  42545     XXXXXX XXXXX            MODEL Point              0.00        1000.00  --W/C--  Cash deposit -   TT22094CYM5K   BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   11:17
      2   0000009540000  42331     XX  XXXX XXXX           MODEL point              0.00        2000.00  --W/C--  Cash deposit -   TT22094JRQX6   BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   12:41
      79  0000005865000  10000150  A A AAAA XXXXXXX        Current Depo         80000.00           0.00  2363714  Cash Withdrawal  TT220947W4JX  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 0254   13:40                                                                 --------------------------------------
      91  0900013591000  70006405  AAAAA. AAAAAA xxx XXXXX Savings Depo         80000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT220944PRDM  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 8426   13:54
      92  0900017904000  90007086  AAAAA AAAAA             Savings Depo       900000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT220945JFS2  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON SQUAR 2160   15:24
      93  0900018400000  40033910  AAAAA AAAAA             Savings Depo         50000.00           0.00  --W/C--  Cash Deposit -   TT22094BYJ1V  BROWN1     BROWN1   LONDON BR8981       13:53'''
)
```

Read the text file (you would replace `sim_txt` with your file name):

```
df = pd.read_fwf(sim_txt, colspecs=([0,9],[25,34],[35,59],[59,999999]))

rcols = {0: 'Ac.Category',
 1: 'Withdral Amt',
 2: 'Deposited Amt',
 3: 'Cheque',
 4: 'Transac.type',
 5: 'Trans.Rf.No',
 6: 'Inputter',
 7: 'Authoriser',
 8: 'Point.Name',
 9: 'Time'}

rgx = (r'(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(\d+:\d\d)')

pd.concat([df[['Sl','Legacy','Account Title']],df.iloc[:,3].str.extract(rgx).rename(columns=rcols)], axis=1)

   Sl    Legacy            Account Title   Ac.Category Withdral Amt Deposited Amt   Cheque     Transac.type   Trans.Rf.No Inputter Authoriser         Point.Name   Time
0   1     42545             XXXXXX XXXXX   MODEL Point         0.00       1000.00  --W/C--   Cash deposit -  TT22094CYM5K   BROWN1     BROWN1  LONDON SQUAR 0254  11:17
1   2     42331            XX  XXXX XXXX   MODEL point         0.00       2000.00  --W/C--   Cash deposit -  TT22094JRQX6   BROWN1     BROWN1  LONDON SQUAR 0254  12:41
2  79  10000150         A A AAAA XXXXXXX  Current Depo     80000.00          0.00  2363714  Cash Withdrawal  TT220947W4JX   BROWN1     BROWN1  LONDON SQUAR 0254  13:40
3  91  70006405  AAAAA. AAAAAA xxx XXXXX  Savings Depo     80000.00          0.00  --W/C--   Cash Deposit -  TT220944PRDM   BROWN1     BROWN1  LONDON SQUAR 8426  13:54
4  92  90007086              AAAAA AAAAA  Savings Depo    900000.00          0.00  --W/C--   Cash Deposit -  TT220945JFS2   BROWN1     BROWN1  LONDON SQUAR 2160  15:24
5  93  40033910              AAAAA AAAAA  Savings Depo     50000.00          0.00  --W/C--   Cash Deposit -  TT22094BYJ1V   BROWN1     BROWN1      LONDON BR8981  13:53
```

The overall logic is that we take the first three columns because they are fixed widths (in our assumption).  That leaves us with the remainder of the line.  We know we can split the columns because they are separated by two blanks all the way up to `Authoriser`.  We then take all the characters between that and the time detect at the end via regex `(\d+:\d\d)` to be the `Point.Name` column data.